# React Native: Why am I not able to re-add an event listener?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, addeventlistener, onesignal, react-native-onesignal

In my React Native app I have two screens `screenA` and `screenB`. I'm using `react-navigation@4.x` and I navigate from `screenA` to `screenB` with `this.props.navigation.navigate('screenB')` and back with `this.props.navigation.goBack()`.

I'm using `OneSignal`, and when `screenA` mounts I add a OneSignal event listener.

**screenA**

```
OneSignal.addEventListener('opened', () => console.log(this.props.navigation.state.routeName));
```

I have the same code in `screenB`, and up until this point, it works as expected. When I'm on
`screenA` and open a push notification, it logs `screenA`, and when I'm on `screenB` it logs `screenB`, because `screenB`'s event listener overrides `screenA`'s.

However, when I navigate back to `screenA`, `screenB`'s event listener is still in place, so I add this code to `screenB` to remove its event listener:

**screenB**

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  OneSignal.removeEventListener('opened');
}
```

and to get `screenA` to re-invoke its event listener, I add this code:

**screenA**

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (!prevProps.isFocused && this.props.isFocused) {
    OneSignal.addEventListener('opened', () => console.log(this.props.navigation.state.routeName));
  }
}
```

**The Problem: **

This `isFocused` condition *is* triggered when I return to `screenA`, so the `addEventListener` code block is reached, but the event listener isn't successfully added.

Does anyone know how I can approach troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/met_element_removeeventlistener.asp)

> To remove event handlers, the function specified with the addEventListener() method must be an external function, like in the example above (myFunction).
> Anonymous functions, like "element.removeEventListener("event", function(){ myScript });" will not work

So, create a function and provide the SAME reference to add/remove event listeners.

**Like this**

```js
componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('opened', this.eventListenerFun);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  window.removeEventListener('opened', this.eventListenerFun);
}

eventListenerFun = () => { 
  // code of your fun goes here....
  //console.log(this.props.navigation.state.routeName);
}
```

Also [see here](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-sdk-setup#step-5---initialize-the-onesignal-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

According to React Navigation's Documentation:
Consider a stack navigator with screens A and B. After navigating to A, its componentDidMount is called. When pushing B, its componentDidMount is also called, but A remains mounted on the stack and its componentWillUnmount is therefore not called.

When going back from B to A, componentWillUnmount of B is called, but componentDidMount of A is not because A remained mounted the whole time.

[Read more...](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-lifecycle/)